# 405 method not allowed in Postman after deploying the API in Railway, but routes are correct and working well in local

Tags: go, postman, railway

I am having an issue with 405 method not allowed in Postman after deploying Railway. My routes are correct and working locally. I've seen some similar issues but the majority of what I've seen are due to typos. The log does not indicate any problems and looks fine. Has anyone ever experienced something similar?

Here is my routes code:

```
package routes

import (
    "tiketAPI/controllers"
    "tiketAPI/middleware"

    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
)

func Routes(e *echo.Echo) {
    // Public routes
    u := e.Group("/users")
    u.POST("/login", controllers.Login)
    u.POST("/register", controllers.Register)

    g := e.Group("/api")
    g.Use(middleware.JwtMiddleware)
    g.GET("/events", controllers.GetEvents)
    g.GET("/events/:id", controllers.GetEventByID)
    g.POST("/events", controllers.CreateEvent)
    g.PUT("/events/:id", controllers.UpdateEvent)
    g.DELETE("/events/:id", controllers.DeleteEvent)
}
```

[image: post req]

My Golang Version : 1.17

I have checked the log carefully and I can't find any errors. The log looks fine. I am expecting to be able to make a request to the endpoint using the method that I am using.

Here are the steps that I have taken to try to resolve the issue:

I have checked the code for errors.
I have checked the configuration to make sure there are no errors.
I have tried all of these things, but I am still getting the 405 error.

I am asking if anyone has ever experienced a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue today and though I'm not sure the specifics of why it's this way with Postman specifically. If you specify your protocol as https://<your link here> I believe that will fix the issue! It did for me at least.